# Não consigo somar "variável = variáveil + 1" no laço while

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
quantidade = int(input("Quantos episódios? "))
inicio = 1
numero_do_post = 379
numero_do_anime = 6
arquivo = open("script.txt", "w")

while (inicio <= quantidade):
    arquivo.write(numero_do_anime)
    inicio = inicio + 1
arquivo.close()
```

Quando vou imprimir a variável ele dá o seguinte erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\script.py", line 11, in <module>
    arquivo.write(numero_do_anime)
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not int
```

Eu quero que ele saia um número seguido:
6,7,8 etc... não entendo o erro.

Comment: O problema não é no `inicio = inicio + 1`, mas sim no `arquivo.write`. A mensagem de erro está dizendo: a função `write` aceita apenas *string* como parâmetro e você está passando um inteiro.

Comment: Então como eu consigo escrever no texto o número, de modo que no próximo laço ele receba ele mesmo + 1?

Comment: O que exatamente quer fazer? Se só corrigir o erro da pergunta será escrito no seu arquivo várias vezes o número 379. Por exemplo, se o usuário digitar 100, no seu arquivo teriam 100 vezes o número 379. Não parece que é isso que você quer, então só resolver o problema não seria suficiente. Poderia descrever detalhadamente o que está tentando fazer e qual é a saída que deseja?

Answer (score 4):

Quando você abre um arquivo com `open()` ele te retorna um objeto do tipo `file object`.

A partir dele você pode escrever no arquivo fazendo `meu_arquivo.write(conteudo)` onde conteudo deve ser uma **string**.

Então, se seus dados não forem uma string acarretará em um erro, como no seu caso, onde você tenta escrever inteiros no arquivo.

Para contornar você deve converter o tipo de dados antes de escrever com algo do tipo:

```
       arquivo.write(str(numero_do_anime))
```

Comment: Então... Isso eu consigo... Problema é que eu quero colocar 6, 7, 8, 9... Não o mesmo número várias vezes entendeu... Esse é o meu problema...

Comment: No seu código você manda escrever no arquivo `numero_do_anime` porém não atualiza o valor da veriável. Por isso, você tem o mesmo valor sempre sendo escrito no arquivo.

Answer (score 0):

Corrigi... Era uma coisa muito boba na verdade...

Eu já tinha feito antes o que o BXL tinha falado. Mas no meu caso era só ter colocado logo após o `arquivo.write(str(numero_do_anime))`... o código: `numero_do_anime = numero_do_anime + 1`